# c#, NullReferenceException: Object хотя он существует

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я новичек в разработе игр и пытаюсь написать скрипт, который будет мне подсчитывать количество монеток и выводит это на экран

Я создал пустой gameObject, туда запихнул мой скрипт
Подключил UI текст туда который я хочу изменять и все работает.

Но иногда ругается, будето этого UI не существует и почему то возвращает null

Мой код

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PickupPoints : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Text coinText;
    private int cointsCount = 0;
    private ScoreManager scoreManager;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    { 
        scoreManager = FindObjectOfType<ScoreManager>();
    }
    
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
        Debug.Log(coinText);
        coinText.text = "Coints = " + cointsCount;
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.name == "Player")
        {
            cointsCount++;
            gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Конкретно ругается на эту строку кода

```
    void Update () 
    {
        Debug.Log(coinText);
        coinText.text = "Coints = " + cointsCount;
    }
```

Здесь видно мой лог
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

мой обьект где я подключил скрипт
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

здесь видно что скрипт подключен и обьект UI также
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

мой UI обьект
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но я получаю NullReferenceException: Object

Как решить эту проблему?
Спасибо.

Comment: Проинициализировать coinText до его использования. У вас он равен null. `public Text coinText = new Text(что-то там);`

Comment: А почему он либо  Null, либо возвращает нормально?

Comment: @AK неее. это Unity. Там в инспекторе ссылка на компонент

Comment: "Но иногда ругается, будето этого UI не существует и почему то возвращает null" --- а иногда это когда? При запуске игры или во время работы то так, то сяк? Или в какой момент?

Comment: Как только я запустил, оно возвращает то null, то мой компонент и так пока работает игра.

Comment: Честно говоря в текущем варианте ничего не вижу. Может где-то ещё есть код, который взаимоедействует с текстом? Или что-то инстанциируется динамически?

Comment: конкретно с этим текстом работает только этот скрипт и я уже голову ломаю но не могу ничего исправить

Comment: Скорее всего вы случайно навесили этот же скрипт или ссылку на текстовое поле на что-то ещё, проверьте. Если не найдёте, то старый-добрый if в коде ещё никто не отменял, коли уж null прилетает только "иногда".